# When is instrumentation involved in app start?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-instrumentation

I have a Xamarin Android app in production, and I see quite a few following crashes in reports in Google Play Developer Console:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:
mono.android.Runtime.register:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V
at mono.android.Runtime.register(Native Method)
at speedcamapp.SpeedcamApplication.onCreate(SpeedcamApplication.java:18)
at
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1008)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4506)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Since this seems like Xamarin bug, [I asked them and I was told](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=27866) the problem is this line :

```
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1008)
```

that it is not normal for app to be started with instrumentation and it means that somebody is "tinkering" with my app.

But I can see many of these errors, from many different devices, and some users even left the message "it stopped working" with their crash report...

I tried googling "android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate" and I found many app logs with this line in log.

So my question is, that does "android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate" really mean? **When can this happen to ordinary user out there?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this is normal stack trace of `Application.onCreate()` method. Instrumetnation is used every time when any lifecycle method's of `Application` or `Activity` is called.

Take a look on this stack trace. I made it in my normal (not Xamarin) application. I launched it without any mention of instrumentation of course:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
    at com.example.asdf.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:11)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

For me it is clear that Instrumentation is envolved every time when `onCreate()` is called. But we can check whether if it is really every time or not. It is in [source code](http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=method&id=repository.grepcode.com%24java%24ext@com.google.android%24android@5.0.2_r1@android%24app@Application@onCreate%28%29&k=u). As you can see `onCreate()` called from a few places:

1. `android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()`
2. `android.app.ActivityThread.attach(boolean)`
3. `android.test.ApplicationTestCase.createApplication()`

(Other calls are `super.onCreate()` and not our case)

`ApplicationTestCase` is not our case obviously. `ActivityThread.attach()` is something similar. But it calls `Application.onCreate()` only for system applications. You can see it if you go above on source code. So the rest is `Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()`.

We can say that you have normal stack trace and nothing special in `Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()`. So your problem with `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is somewhere else. Unfortunately I didn't use Xamarin and I cannot help you with it

Comment: You're correct; `Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()` is always called.  What's confusing here is that, afaict, `System.loadLibrary("monodroid")` *should* be called as part of `installContentProviders()`, which is *before* `callApplicationOnCreate()`, yet the symbol isn't found. Why isn't the symbol found?